# Trying to add 1 to an integer array for every value. JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, int

```
(int i=0; i < n; i++){
for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
    Array[i][j]=Array[i][j] + 1;
    }
}
```

for some reason I am getting an error. Array is an int array filled with 0s. n can be any size. The error i keep getting is exception in main thread for the Array line. Am I not adding 1 to the array correctly?

edit: error was called exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 3
at (where that one line is)

edit: it was initialized with

```
       Array = new int[n][n];
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
            Array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

but this doesn't seem to be a part of the error

Comment: Please post the full error and stack trace.

Comment: What's the exception? How do you initialize `Array`?

Comment: how did you declare `Array`? Also I assume there is a `for` missing in your code (first line: `for(int i=0; ...`

Comment: "I am getting an error" is *never* enough detail. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: The Initialization will not work that way, you need the right type for your array and I would recommend you to give it another name as you will get problems if you need `java.lang.Array` or `*.Array`, it is better practice to give it a name that starts with a lower case character.

Comment: it does not produce any exception in my system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> edit: error was called exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: 3

Right. That means that your array isn't big enough. It's not clear whether the *first* dimension is only 2 or the second, but one of them isn't correct. You should have something like:

```
int[][] array = new int[n][n];
```

somewhere. If you haven't, you should look at what you've *actually* got.

A better alternative - would be to use the length of the array in the `for` loop as the bound:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = array[i][j] + 1;
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int[] row = array[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        row[j] = row[j] + 1;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int[] row = array[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        row[j]++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: You now *claim* it really was initialized like this:

```
Array = new int[n][n];
```

If that's the case, then the value of `n` must have been changed since initialization, so it's effectively irrelevant. If the value of `n` hasn't changed, your original code simply won't throw that exception.

Comment: My error was hidden elsewhere. Your answer was not wrong though. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use proper length, `Array.length` will be length of 1d of the `Array` and `Array[i].length` will be length of 2d -

```
for(int i=0; i < Array.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < Array[i].length; j++){
        Array[i][j]=Array[i][j] + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it really was initialized like this:

```
int[][] Array;
Array = new int[n][n];
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
        Array[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

*And* if neither `Array` nor `n` nor `Array[i]` for any `i` were changed inbetween then the following code *will* work:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
        Array[i][j]=Array[i][j] + 1;
    }
}
```

So either your code is changing one of the things mentioned or your question is bogus...

(BTW: I strongly recommend calling that `Array`different, at least call it `array`...)